# Broadly, I'm looking for ways to possibly condense my very repetitious code. Specifically, trying to access multiple states with the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, refactoring

This is my first post asking for help so I apologize if it is too longwinded or not specific enough. I am working on a personal project to buff up my react/javascript skills. I am building a dice rolling application for tabletop gaming. The goal is for the user to be able to roll any number of a single sized die, and also be able to roll multiple sizes at the same time. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzMUY.png) just to give you an idea of how the forms look. I haven't added any styling so this is not representative of the final look. Just posted to give you an idea of the forms having their own buttons for single size rolls and a separate button for multiple sizes.

I have the functionality for both working, however, my code is extremely repetitive and I feel like there is a way I can avoid repeating the same loops/functions over and over with just a number change here or there.

I have each size (d4-d100) separated out into components. Here is an example of the Four Sided Die. Each of the others is identical aside from the numbers and names.

```
import { Button, Card, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import React from 'react'
import { D4 } from '../img/index'


class Four extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.onD4Change(event.target.value)
    }
        
    rollDice(sides) {
        this.props.onRollDice(sides)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Card body style={{ width: '400px' }}>
                    <Form class='form'>
                        <Form.Group controlId='amount'></Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>How many dice do you want to roll?</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            name='d4'
                            d4Amount={this.props.d4Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            min='0'
                        />
                        <Form.Group />
                    </Form>
                    <Button variant='warning' onClick={() => this.rollDice(4)}>
                        D4
                        <img src={D4} alt='four sided die' />
                    </Button>
                </Card>
            </>
        )
    }
}
export default Four;
```

And here is the App that they are plugged into.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import './App.scss'
import { Four, Six, Eight, Ten, Twelve, Twenty, Hundred } from './dice/index'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            result: 0,
            // amount: 1,
            d4Amount: 0,
            d6Amount: 0,
            d8Amount: 0,
            d10Amount: 0,
            d12Amount: 0,
            d20Amount: 0,
            d100Amount: 0,
            numsRolled: '',
            rolledPrint: '',
            diceRolled: '',
            total: 0,
            multipleRolledPrint: ''
        }

        this.handleD4Change = this.handleD4Change.bind(this)
        this.handleD6Change = this.handleD6Change.bind(this)
        this.handleD8Change = this.handleD8Change.bind(this)
        this.handleD10Change = this.handleD10Change.bind(this)
        this.handleD12Change = this.handleD12Change.bind(this)
        this.handleD20Change = this.handleD20Change.bind(this)
        this.handleD100Change = this.handleD100Change.bind(this)
        this.rollDice = this.rollDice.bind(this)
    }

    handleD4Change(d4Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d4Amount: d4Amount,
        })
    }

    handleD6Change(d6Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d6Amount: d6Amount,
        })
    }

    handleD8Change(d8Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d8Amount: d8Amount,
        })
    }

    handleD10Change(d10Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d10Amount: d10Amount,
        })
    }

    handleD12Change(d12Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d12Amount: d12Amount,
        })
    }

    handleD20Change(d20Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d20Amount: d20Amount,
        })
    }

    handleD100Change(d100Amount) {
        this.setState({
            d100Amount: d100Amount,
        })
    }

    rollDice = (sides) => {
        let numsRolled = []
        let result = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.amount; i++) {
            numsRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * sides))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < numsRolled.length; i++) {
            result += numsRolled[i]
        }
        console.log(`You rolled ${numsRolled.join()}`)
        console.log(`Giving a total of ${result}`)
        let rolledPrint = numsRolled.join(' + ')

        this.setState({
            result: result,
            numsRolled: numsRolled,
            rolledPrint: rolledPrint,
        })
    }

    rollMultipleDice = () => {
        let total = 0
        let diceRolled = []
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d4Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d6Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d8Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d10Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d12Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d20Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.d100Amount; i++) {
            diceRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < diceRolled.length; i++) {
            total += diceRolled[i]
        }

        console.log(`You rolled ${diceRolled.join()}`)
        console.log(`Giving a total of ${total}`)
        let multipleRolledPrint = diceRolled.join(' + ')
        this.setState({
            diceRolled: diceRolled,
            total: total,
            multipleRolledPrint: multipleRolledPrint
        })

        
    }

    render() {
        

        return (
            <>
                <div className='App'>
                    <Form class='form'>
                        <Four
                            name='amount'
                            d4Amount={this.state.d4Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD4Change={this.handleD4Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(4)}
                        />
                        <Six
                            name='amount'
                            d6Amount={this.state.d6Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD6Change={this.handleD6Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(6)}
                        />
                        <Eight
                            name='amount'
                            d8Amount={this.state.d8Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD8Change={this.handleD8Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(8)}
                        />
                        <Ten
                            name='amount'
                            d10Amount={this.state.d10Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD10Change={this.handleD10Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(10)}

                        />
                        <Twelve
                            name='amount'
                            d12Amount={this.state.d12Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD12Change={this.handleD12Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(12)}
                        />
                        <Twenty
                            name='amount'
                            d20Amount={this.state.d20Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD20Change={this.handleD20Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(20)}
                        />
                        <Hundred
                            name='amount'
                            d100Amount={this.state.d100Amount}
                            placeholder='#'
                            onD100Change={this.handleD100Change}
                            type='number'
                            class='formControl'
                            onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(100)}
                        />
                        <Button variant='danger' onClick={() => 
                         this.rollMultipleDice()}>Roll All</Button>
                    </Form>

                    <div id='rolled dice'>You rolled: {this.state.rolledPrint}</div>
                    <div id='result'>Totaling: {this.state.result}</div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

The main issue is all of the "handleChange", binds, and the for loops. Is there a way to condense this and have less code to run all of these changes and loops?

I feel like I'm missing something here with this original rollDice function.

```
rollDice = (sides) => {
        let numsRolled = []
        let result = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.amount; i++) {
            numsRolled.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * sides))
        }
```

It was working before when I had just one input and was rolling one kind of die at a time. Now it is not functioning unless I specifically change this.state.amount to something like this.state.d4Amount. Is there a way for me to access the state of all the input fields at the same time so I can have the button specific on each type of die roll just for itself, or do I have to now add a new version of this function to each component?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

#### 1. define a state like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dice: [
                { id: 'D4',   label: 'D4',   sides: 4,   amount: 0 },
                { id: 'D6',   label: 'D6',   sides: 6,   amount: 0 },
                { id: 'D8',   label: 'D8',   sides: 8,   amount: 0 },
                { id: 'D10',  label: 'D10',  sides: 10,  amount: 0 },
                { id: 'D12',  label: 'D12',  sides: 12,  amount: 0 },
                { id: 'D20',  label: 'D20',  sides: 20,  amount: 0 },
                { id: 'D100', label: 'D100', sides: 100, amount: 0 },
            ],
            ...
```

Maybe this already leads you towards a solution, if you do some consequent refactoring.

#### 2. Create one generic `Die` component

e.g. copy `Four.jsx` and change all *specific* props into *generic* props, like:

```
class Die extends React.Component {
    ...
    handleChange( event ){
        this.props.onChange( this.props.id, event.target.value );
    }

    rollDice() {
        this.props.onRollDice( this.props.sides );
    }
    ...
    <Form.Control
        name={ 'amount' }
        amount={ this.props.amount }
        placeholder='#'
        onChange={ this.handleChange }
        type='number'
        class='formControl'
        min='0'
    />
    ...
    <Button variant='warning' onClick={ this.rollDice }>
        { this.props.label }
        { <img src={ this.props.id } alt={ this.props.title } /> }
    </Button>
```

#### 3. create all the repeating code using the `state.dice` array

The form:

```
...
<Form class='form'>
    { this.state.dice.map( die => {
        return <Die
            id={ die.id }
            label={ die.label }
            amount={ die.amount }
            sides={ die.sides }
            onChange={ this.handleChange }
            onRollDice={ this.rollDice }
        />;
    }) }
    <Button variant='danger' onClick={ this.rollMultipleDice }>Roll All</Button>
</Form>
...
```

The `rollMultipleDice()` method:

```
...
this.state.dice.forEach( die => {
    ...
    for( let i = 0; i < die.amount; i++ ){
        diceRolled.push( Math.ceil(Math.random() * die.sides ) )
    }
    ...
})
...
```

#### Refactoring duplicated code in general

Your code might look quite overwhelming when thinking about how to refactor the whole thing at once, but I like to solve problems like that by just starting anywhere to remove code duplication, and I find that works quite well.

Pick *anythink* that looks like duplicated, e.g.

```
handleD20Change(d20Amount) {
    this.setState({
        d20Amount: d20Amount,
    })
}
```

create a new method, that doesn't have this duplication:

```
handleChange(amount) {
    this.setState({
        // TODO: what to put here ?
        //   It might already come to your mind at this point,
        //   or you just finish it later.
    })
}
```

Or take the form:

```
<Four
    name='amount'
    d4Amount={this.state.d4Amount}
    placeholder='#'
    onD4Change={this.handleD4Change}
    type='number'
    class='formControl'
    onRollDice={() => this.rollDice(4)}
/>
<Six ... />
<Eight ... />
```

You already know that in the end you want no duplication, i.e. only one component like:

```
[/* TODO: what comes here ? */].map( dieData => <Die
    name='amount'
    placeholder='#'
    type='number'
    class='formControl'
    onRollDice={ () => { /* ??? */ } }
/> )
```

But you might not know exactly how it shold be implemented, so as an intermediate step just "blindly" start implementing that `Die` component, even if you just **move the whole duplication** into it as a first step. Where ever you notice some data is missing, just add it as a prop. It's ok for now if you introduce many props, you can optimize that later. E.g.:

```
class Die extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        if( this.props.type === 'D4' ){
            return <Four
                name='amount'
                d4Amount={ this.props.amount }
                placeholder='#'
                onD4Change={ this.props.handleChange }
                type='number'
                class='formControl'
                onRollDice={ this.props.onRollDice }
            />
        } else if( this.props.type === 'D6' ){
            <Six ... />
        } else if ...
```

And call this generic component instead of the specific ones:

```
<div className='App'>
    <Form class='form'>
        <Die
            ... any other specific props needed ...
            type={ 'D4' }
            amount={ this.state.d4Amount }
            onChange={ this.handleD4Change }
            onRollDice={ () => this.rollDice( 4 ) }
        />
        <Die
            ... any other specific props needed ...
            type={ 'D6' }
            amount={ this.state.d6Amount }
            onChange={ this.handleD6Change }
            onRollDice={ () => this.rollDice( 6 ) }
        />
        <Die
            ... any other specific props needed ...
            type={ 'D8' }
            amount={ this.state.d8Amount }
            onChange={ this.handleD8Change }
            onRollDice={ () => this.rollDice( 8 ) }
        />
```

In my experience this way sooner or later everything starts to make sense, and further steps become more and more obvious.

Just be prepared that it might take some time, listen to some music and start moving code ;-)

Comment: wow!! Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. This approach really seems like the direction I want to head in. It makes a lot of sense and is definitely the type of code I want to write.  It will take me some time to look over it all and adapt my code so I can't say that I've implemented it yet, but I'm going to get started plugging away now. :)